# Calculating time difference between two dates

Tags: mysql

I have data similar to the following:

```
`date1`     `date2`
2013-04-02  NULL    
2013-03-26  NULL
2013-03-26  2013-03-06
2013-03-25  2013-03-05
```

I would like to find the difference in days. For example:

```
`date1`     `date2`    `difference`
2013-04-02  NULL        NULL
2013-03-26  NULL        NULL
2013-03-26  2013-03-27  1.0 # DAYS 
2013-03-25  2013-03-28  3.0
```

How would I calculate this difference?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: date2.Subtract(date1).TotalDays;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a DATEDIFF function.

```
DATEDIFF(date1,date2)
```

The following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2014-11-30','2014-11-29') AS DiffDate
```

Output will be.

```
DiffDate
1
```